# How to set values with a button in edit form SharePoint designer 2013

Tags: xml, vb.net, datetime, xslt, sharepoint-2013

I want to know how to code a button that sets the current date and time in the Field "End Date" in a task List.

I used SharePoint designer to add the button but I can not figure out how to set current time to the selected item with code.

I have this line of code, but I can not set the value to the field, it returns just a "false":

```
<td nowrap="nowrap" class="ms-vb" width="99%">
  <input name="Button1" type="button" value="button" onclick="{@End_x0020_Date = ddwrt:TodayIso()}" />
  <xsl:text xmlns:ddwrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/runtime" ddwrt:nbsp-preserve="yes" disable-output-escaping="yes">&amp;nbsp;</xsl:text>
</td>
</xsl:template>
```

What am i missing?

Many thanks!!

Comment: <td nowrap="nowrap" class="ms-vb" width="99%"><input name="Button1" type="button" value="button" onclick="{@End_x0020_Date = ddwrt:TodayIso()}" />
  
   <xsl:text xmlns:ddwrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/runtime" ddwrt:nbsp-preserve="yes" disable-output-escaping="yes">&amp;nbsp;</xsl:text> 
   
  </td></xsl:template>

Comment: Just in case it's useful, &nbsp; Usually means space.